# Morphia connection pool?

Tags: mongodb, connection-pooling, morphia, nosql

Is there a way to configure the connection pool properties of Morphia?  I see the connection count increase appropriately in the console as I run multiple, concurrent tests against my application.  However, I have been unable to locate any documentation that explains how to configure the initial number of connections, timeouts, size of the pool, etc.

Any resources you can point me to that would explain how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would tune that through the Mongo (or MongoClient) you use to connect.  Morphia itself doesn't do any pooling.  More documentation on the java driver can be found here:  http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java/